# Задачка с физики на С++

Tags: c++, физика

Railroad

---

Новый поезд «Интерсити» проходит заключительный этап испытаний. Одно из заданий этого этапа - проехать от станции А до станции В, расстояние между которыми равно L в следующем режиме: разогнаться с ускорением a1 до скорости, не более V, проехать с этой скоростью время, не меньшее t, остановиться на станции В , тормозя с ускорением по модулю а2. Рассчитайте минимальное время движения поезда.

---

Технические условия. Программа Railroad читает с устройства стандартного ввода числа L, a1, a2, v, t. через пробел. Величины L, a1, a2, v - положительные, вещественные; t - неотрицательное, вещественное, целая часть всех величин не более 10 в 3 степени. Программа выводит на устройство стандартного вывода единственное число - время нахождения поезда в пути с точностью 10 в -4 степени.

---

Примеры

Ввод 40.5 0.5 0.6 3 7.5

Вывод 19.00000000

Ввод 20.5 0.5 0.6 3 7.5

Вывод 14.37300711

> Можете сказать что надо тут находить и по каким формулам, код напишу сам. Спасибо зарание!

Comment: Физики тут, мягко говоря, нет...  https://foxford.ru/wiki/fizika/pryamolineynoe-ravnouskorennoe-dvizhenie#:~:text=%D0%9F%D1%80%D1%8F%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B9%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5%20%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%83%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5%20%D0%B4%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5%20%E2%80%93%20%D0%B4%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5%20%D0%BF%D0%BE,%24%2C%20%D0%B2%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%8F%20%24t%24.

Comment: Учебные задания допустимы в качестве вопросов только при условии, что вы пытались решить их самостоятельно перед тем, как задать вопрос. Пожалуйста, отредактируйте вопрос и укажите, что именно вызвало у вас трудности при решении задачи. Например, приведите код, который вы написали, пытаясь решить задачу

Answer (score 1, accepted):

по формулам

```
v = v0 + at
s = v0t + at^2/2
```

т.е. вы должны подсчитать

1. сколько времени поезд будет разгоняться до скорости v1 с ускорением a1
2. сколько он за это время проедет расстояние
3. сколько времени поезд будет тормозить от скорости v1 с ускорением a2
4. сколько он за это время проедет расстояние
5. из 2) и 4) вычислить какое расстояние он ехал с максимальной скоростью
6. вычислить время такого движения
7. сложить найденные времена

Еще хорошо бы учесть эффекты специальной и общей теории относительности, но подозреваю, что в школе их еще не давали

Comment: А at^2/2 значит   ((a*t)квадрат) / 2?

Comment: да - `0.5*a*t^2`, есть ускорение - скорость - это интеграл по времени для ускорения - `v = at`, а пройденное расстояние - это интеграл по времени для скорости - `s = at*t/2`