# Задание на скорость и время С++

Tags: c++

Есть задание:

Есть поезд, который должен пройти путь от А до В в следующем режиме - разогнаться с ускорением a1 до скорости, не более V, проехать с этой скоростью время, не менее t, остановиться на станции В, тормозя с ускорением по модулю А2. Рассчитайте минимальное время движения поезда.

Мой код:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>   
#include <iomanip> 
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    double l,a1,a2,v,t,t1,t2,t3, l1,l2,l3;
    cin >> l >> a1 >> a2 >> v >> t;        //40.5 0.5 0.6 3 7.5 пример
    t1 = v / a1;              
    
    l1 = (a1 * pow(t1,2)) / 2;   
    
    t3 = v / a2;         
    
    l3 = (a2 * pow(t3,2)) / 2;  
    
    // l2 = l - (l1 + l3);
    // cout << l1 << " " << l2 << " " << l3 << endl;
    // cout << t1 << " " << t2 << " " << t3 << endl;
    
    if (l1+l2+l3 <= l)             
    {
       l2 = l - (l1 + l3);        
       t2 = l2 / v;             
       cout << t1 + t2 + t3 << endl;
    }
    else if (l1+l2+l3 > l)       
    {
       v =  ???? ;                               /// на сколько уменьшить скорость?          
       
       t1 = v / a1;
    
       l1 = (a1 * pow(t1,2)) / 2;
    
       t3 = v / a2;
    
       l3 = (a2 * pow(t3,2)) / 2;
       
       l2 = l - (l1 + l3);
       
       t2 = l2 / v;
       
       
       cout << t1 + t2 + t3 << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Задачка с физики на С++](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1192398/%d0%97%d0%b0%d0%b4%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d1%81-%d1%84%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%b8%d0%ba%d0%b8-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d0%a1)

Comment: Но там нет кода

Comment: задание есть, а вопроса нет... В чем вопрос то?

Comment: На сколько надо уменьшить скорость если поезд проходит больше чем надо?

Comment: так задача решается чисто аналитически. Или нет?

Answer (score 2):

Возможны два случая.

Если поезд достигает максимальной скорости V, то первый этап проходится за время `t1 = V/a1`, третий за `t3 = V/a2`, а время второго можно найти из соотношения для пути

```
L = V^2/(2*a1) + V^2/(2*a2) + t2*V
t2 = L/V - V/(2*a1) + V/(2*a2)
```

Если время `t2>=t`, то именно этот случай даёт минимальное время `t1+t2+t3`

Иначе время второго этапа `t2=t`. Если время первого `t1`, то достигается скорость `v=t1*a1`, время третьего этапа `t3=t1*a1/a2`, и соотношение для пути

```
L = a1*t1^2/2 + a1*t1*t + t1^2*a1^2/(2*a2)
```

Решается квадратное уравнение относительно t1, находится t1, из него t3 и общее время

Вариант - за базовое неизвестное возьмём скорость v:

```
 L = v^2/(2*a1) + v*t + v^2/(2*a2)
```

и квадратное уравнение относительно v решаем.

Answer (score 1):

такие задачи решаются аналитически (если это не школа):

Движение можно разбить на 3 этапа:

этап 1 - разгон

```
v = a1 * t1    
s1 = a1 * t1^2 / 2
```

этап 2 - равномерное движение

```
s2 = v * t2 = a1 * t1 * t2
```

этап 3 - торможение

```
t3 = v / a2 = a1 / a2 * t1
s3 = a2 * t3^2 / 2
```

Итого:

```
S = s1 + s2 + s3 = a1 * t1^2 / 2 + a1 * t1 * t2 + a2 * t3^2 / 2 = a1 * t1^2 / 2 + a1 * t1 * t2 + a2 * (a1 / a2 * t1)^2 / 2
T = t1 + t2 + t3 = t1 + t2 + a1 / a2 * t1
```

откуда:

```
S = a1 * t1^2 / 2 + a1 * t1 * t2 + a1^2 / a2 * t1^2 / 2
t2 = (S - a1 * t1^2 / 2 - a1^2 / a2 * t1^2 / 2) / (a1 * t1)
```

Итоговое время:

```
T = t1 + (S - a1 * t1^2 / 2 - a1^2 / a2 * t1^2 / 2) / (a1 * t1) + a1 / a2 * t1
```

Надо найти такое `t`, чтобы `T` было минимальным, т.е. надо найти

```
T' = 0

T' = 0.5 * (a1 / a2 - 2S / (a1 * t1^2) + 1)
```

откуда

```
t1 = sqrt(2s / (a1 * (a1 / a2 + 1)))
```

Дальше надо проверить - входит ли `t1` в ограничение, т.е. `a1*t1 <= v`,

если входит - то это искомый ответ

если не входит - то `t1 = a1 / v`